# EmguCV - FourCC cannot be set (.Net 6)

Tags: c#, opencv, .net-6.0, emgucv

I am using emguCV for capturing video from usb camera. I want to set fourCC but when I check the fourCC It **set** **0** automatically. Then , Capturing is not working.

When I use default fourCC settings, it set **"22"**. although it is, capturing is working . But 22 is not an fourCC enum. I am confused.

**EDIT:**
I changed the api to DSHOW then I could set the fourCC but now I can not save with VideoWriter error: **"Unable to create VideoWriter. Make sure you have the specific codec installed"**

**EDIT 2:**
If I not give the codec code to VideoWriter I can get the record.

```
  var props = new Tuple<CapProp, int>[]
  {
      new(CapProp.FrameWidth,1280),
      new(CapProp.FrameHeight,800),
      new(CapProp.Fps,120),
      new(CapProp.FourCC,VideoWriter.Fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')),


  };
  videoCapture = new VideoCapture(index, VideoCapture.API.Msmf,props);
  apiIndex = CameraHelper.GetApiIndex("MSMF");

  var fps = videoCapture.Get(CapProp.Fps);
  var s = videoCapture.Get(CapProp.FourCC);
```

I want to set FourCC setting with emguCV.